# Python Reg expression to delete all text inside quotation marks

Tags: python, expression

I have a body of text like this:

```
According to James, "we do not know" the source of the problem, "we are clueless".
```

What kind of regex would delete all the text inside the quotation marks?  I have used re.sub with parantheses but I cannot come up with an expression to identify "s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = 'According to James, "we do not know" the source of the problem, "we are clueless".'
re.sub('".+?"', '', text)
```